# ionic 3, angular 5 API integration

Tags: angular, api, ionic3, angular5

I'm trying to include an API with my new ionic application. I'm using Ionic 3.9.2 which uses Angularjs 5. I don't have any experience with these newer updates.

This is included in my data.ts file (my provider)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

   private url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/opju3";

   constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
     console.log('Hello DataProvider test4');
   }

   getData(){
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .subscribe(response => this.response = response.json());
   }

}
```

In my home.ts file I have this code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataProvider: 
DataProvider) {
    console.log("before.getData");

  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.dataProvider.getData();  
  }

}
```

It may be worth noting that I'm running it in the Cloud9 IDE so I don't have the best error messages. When I run it currently, the errors I receive are:

```
 [16:17:43]  typescript: src/providers/data/data.ts, line: 16 
        Property 'response' does not exist on type 'DataProvider'. 

  L15:  return this.http.get(this.url)
  L16:  .subscribe(response => this.response = response.json());

  [16:17:43]  typescript: src/providers/data/data.ts, line: 16 
        Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'. 

  L15:  return this.http.get(this.url)
  L16:  .subscribe(response => this.response = response.json());
```

Thank you all!

EDIT: 
You all answered my question perfectly. It is working without a hitch now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which kind of data are you trying to retrieve? Here is the issue:  ```.subscribe(response => this.response = response.json());```

Comment: Junior Gantin is correct, that is the problem line. Read the HttpClient tutorial :) https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `HttpClient` by default formats the response to JSON so we no longer need to parse it using `response.json():` if you want to parse your response you should use `map` operator which is used to parse the response in the desired format in your case its json and it returns an observable which shall be subscribed.
For example:

```
this.httpClient.get(this.url)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
```

But it's not required anymore 
  Modify your code : data.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
     getData():Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get(this.url);

       }
```

home.ts

```
 ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.dataProvider.getData().subscribe(value=>{console.log(value);//your logic});  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

About the **first error**:

```
Property 'response' does not exist on type 'DataProvider'.
```

You don't have a `response` property in your class `DataProvider`. You can solve it declaring the property:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

   private url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/opju3";
   private response: any;
   ...
```

About your **second error**:

```
Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Angular `HttpClient` already returns **the body of the response**, and not the `HttpResponse` (unless you use the [observe option](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)). So you don't need to call `response.json()`:

```
.subscribe(response => this.response = response);
```

I advise you to return the observable from your service and subscribing to it in your page, like in the [answer from @Vikas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927494/4850646).